# Google genericdao framework performing unnecessary selects with Maven, Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, genericdao

I am using Hibernate 4.2.11 Final, Spring 3.2.4 and Google Genericdao 1.2.0:

My SpringConfig.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- Specifying that this project is using annotation based Dependency Injection or IOC -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//URL:PORT/SERVICENAME" />
        <property name="username" value="ID" />
        <property name="password" value="Password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.company.client.hibernate.domain.Te</value>
                <value>com.company.client.hibernate.domain.TeComment</value>
                <value>com.company.client.hibernate.domain.TeReason</value>
                <value>com.company.client.hibernate.domain.TeStatus</value>
                <value>com.company.client.hibernate.domain.TeType</value>
                <value>com.company.client.hibernate.domain.TeTypeToReasonMapping</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean   id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
</beans>
```

I have two tables: Reasons and Comments.

The reasons table has 3 columns:

1. ID - Is the PK populated using a sequence.
2. Code - Has a unique constraint against it and is a varchar field.
3. Description - varchar with text

The comments table has 4 columns:

1. ID - Is the PK populated using a sequence.
2. ReasonCode - Has a FK with the reasons table.
3. Order - Integer - has a unique constraint with it and reason code.
4. Comment - varchar with text

I am using annotations for both Hibernate and Spring.

My Reason Domain object has

```
private BigDecimal reasonId;
private String reasonCode;
private String reasonDescription;
private List<TeComment> comments;

@Column(name = "REASON_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getReasonId() {

@Column(name = "REASON_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getReasonCode() {

@Column(name = "REASON_DESCRIPTION", nullable = false, length = 1024)
public String getReasonDescription() {

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "reason")
public List<TeComment> getComments() {
```

My Comments Domain object has:

```
private BigDecimal commentId;
private String commentDescription;
private String reasonCode;
private BigDecimal commentOrder;
private TeReason reason;

@Column(name = "COMMENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getCommentId() {

@Column(name = "REASON_CODE", nullable = false, length = 20, insertable=false, updatable=false)
public String getReasonCode() {

@Column(name = "COMMENT_DESCRIPTION", nullable = false, length = 1024)
public String getCommentDescription() {

@Column(name = "COMMENT_ORDER", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public BigDecimal getCommentOrder() {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "REASON_CODE", referencedColumnName = "REASON_CODE")
public TeReason getReason() {
```

I am also creating a business service layer and creating test scripts for it.  Two methods in the business service layer are:

```
public List<ReasonDTO> retrieveAllReasonsAsDTO(); 
public List<CommentDTO> retrieveAllCommentsAsDTO();
```

They are implemented as:

```
@Autowired
private TeCommentDAO teCommentDao;

@Autowired
private TeReasonDAO teReasonDao;

@Override
@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
public List<ReasonDTO> retrieveAllReasonsAsDTO() {
    return ConvertDomainDTO.convertTeReasonDomainToDTO_List(teReasonDao.findAll());
} // retrieveAllReasonsAsDTO

@Override
@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
public List<CommentDTO> retrieveAllCommentsAsDTO() {
    Search search = new Search(TeComment.class);
    search.addFetch("reason");

    List<TeComment> list = teCommentDao.search(search);
    return ConvertDomainDTO.convertTeCommentDomainToDTO_List(list);
} // retrieveAllCommentsAsDTO
```

My JUNIT test is:

```
List<ReasonDTO> allReasons = businessService.retrieveAllReasonsAsDTO();
assertEquals(allReasons.size(), beginningReasonSize);

List<CommentDTO> allComments = businessService.retrieveAllCommentsAsDTO();
assertEquals(allComments.size(), beginningCommentSize);
```

I am having an issue where hibernate is ignoring the inner join dictated by the "addFetch" and is retrieving all the reasons individually.  I sort of have it solved, but don't understand why it is working this way.

There are two solutions:

1. I change the order of the test script.  So instead of retrieving AllReasons first, I retrieve AllComments first and then allReasons.  In this case the inner join is honored and the reasons are not retrieved individually.
2. I change the transaction propagation from REQUIRED to REQUIRES_NEW on the Comments business method.  In this case the inner join is honored and the reasons are not retrieved individually.

Clearly the issue has to do with sharing a transaction and the order of the retrieve, but I am not sure why.  Does anyone have some insight for me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A question this size rarely gets anyone's attention, because it's way to long (though I can be proven wrong). Your problem is a hibernate problem, perhaps you should focus on that? Please read [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Question has been reformatted in an attempt to boil it down to the nitty-gritty.

Comment: You have provided a lot of code here, please consider revising your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)